# Fixed item jumps around while scrolling - only in MacOS Safari

Tags: css, macos, safari

I have a webpage styled with a fixed side menu inside a div with following css styles:

```
div#sidemenu
{
  top: 120px; left: 800px;
  width: 135px; 
  height: 560px;
  background-image: url(img/bg.png);
  position: fixed;  
  z-index: 30;
}
```

The div is simple:

```
<div id="sidemenu">
<ul>
<li>link1</li>
...
<li>linkn</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It should stay fixed while you scroll down the page.

It works in all non-Safari browsers (IE, FF, OP) on Windows and MacOS, even in the Windows version of Safari - but not in MacOS Safari.

**In MacOS Safari it stays fixed, but jumps/trembles/shivers up and down while scrolling.**

I researched for this issue for a while, compared css abilities, decreased z-index and tried fixing on bottom. Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone experienced such a thing, too? And: Could you fix it?

Additional information:

- the bg image is a png with transparencies
- the bg image is perfectly sized like the container div

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar experiences with jumping bg images and one workaround that seems to be cross browser is to add a div inside the wrapping div. An important thing is to give the new div a height, otherwise mobile safari might have it adjusting on scroll.

```
<div id="sidemenu">
<div id="bg"></div>
<ul>
<li>link1</li>
...
<li>linkn</li>
</ul>
</div>
div#sidemenu
{
  top: 120px; left: 800px;
  width: 135px; 
  height: 560px;
  position: fixed;  
  z-index: 30;
}

#bg {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(img/bg.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```